# Addition of two elements is equal to next elements

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.io.*;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int i = 0;
        int add = 0;

        int a[] = {4, 1, 1, -6};

        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            add = add + a[i];

            if (add - a[i + 1] == 0) {
                System.out.println("exist");

            }
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting as below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at Arraylist1.main(Arraylist1.java:21)
```

Comment: in end of for i equal a.length, so, you has not a[i+1] element.

Comment: And hint: you want us to spend our time to help you. So you please spend the 1 minute it takes to properly format/indent all of your input. That **preview** section close to the edit window, and all the helpful explanations there ... are there for a reason!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are already increment your index in :

```
if (add - a[i + 1] == 0) {
//----------^---^
```

To solve your problem you have to iterate until `a.length - 1` instead of `a.length`, because the last index is 3 so when you try to get `a[3+1]` it will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception because this index is not exit